# After migrating project to Androidx, Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'. > 1 exception was raised by workers:

Tags: android, androidx

What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class androidx.collection.LruCache found in modules collection-1.0.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ServiceCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.content.IntentCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.content.pm.ActivityInfoCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.database.DatabaseUtilsCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.os.ParcelableCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.os.ParcelableCompatCreatorCallbacks found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.util.DebugUtils found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.util.LogWriter found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.util.TimeUtils found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.view.MenuCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.view.MotionEventCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.view.VelocityTrackerCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.view.ViewCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.view.ViewConfigurationCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.view.ViewGroupCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEventCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat$AccessibilityStateChangeListenerCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.widget.EdgeEffectCompat found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.2) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorAdapter found in modules classes.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorAdapter$ChangeObserver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorAdapter$MyDataSetObserver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorFilter found in modules classes.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorFilter$CursorFilterClient found in modules classes.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter found in modules classes.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter found in modules classes.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter$CursorToStringConverter found in modules classes.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter$ViewBinder found in modules classes.jar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord$Op found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.BackStackState found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.BackStackState$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.Fragment found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$SavedState found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$SavedState$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$NonConfigurationInstances found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$BackStackEntry found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$OnBackStackChangedListener found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$3 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$4 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment$2 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.SuperNotCalledException found in modules classes.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.CursorLoader found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.Loader found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.Loader$ForceLoadContentObserver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.Loader$OnLoadCompleteListener found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$2 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$3 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$4 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$AsyncTaskResult found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$Status found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$WorkerRunnable found in modules classes.jar (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager found in modules classes.jar (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$BroadcastRecord found in modules classes.jar (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$ReceiverRecord found in modules classes.jar (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter found in modules classes.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerTitleStrip found in modules classes.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerTitleStrip$PageListener found in modules classes.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager found in modules classes.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$2 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$ItemInfo found in modules classes.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$LayoutParams found in modules classes.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$OnAdapterChangeListener found in modules classes.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$OnPageChangeListener found in modules classes.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$PagerObserver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$SavedState found in modules classes.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$SavedState$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
  Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$SimpleOnPageChangeListener found in modules classes.jar (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0) and jetified-support-v4-r6.jar (com.google.android:support-v4:r6)
```

Comment: gradle.properties

android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx536m



 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
Android Studio 3.4.2


 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'


and 
 buildToolsVersion '29.0.0'

Comment: Post your gradle as well

Comment: @SatishKumar did you find anything?